# shadowRoot.activeElement is not working in safari

Tags: web-component, shadow-dom, stenciljs

Currently I am working on stencilJS which has feature to implement shadow dom. I am facing an issue related to activeElement of the shadowRoot.It is working fine with Chrome but when I am testing my component then activeElement is getting null in safari.

Here is the code snippet

```
import { Component, Prop, Listen } from '@stencil/core';

@Component({
  tag: 'my-component',
  styleUrl: 'my-component.css',
  shadow: true
})
export class MyComponent {
  /**
   * The first name
   */
  @Prop() first: string;

  /**
   * The middle name
   */
  @Prop() middle: string;

  /**
   * The last name
   */
  @Prop() last: string;

  @Listen('click')
  onHadnleClickEvent(ev) {
    console.log('===== 31 =====', ev.target.shadowRoot.activeElement)// getting null in safari
  }

  render() {
    return ( <div>
        <button>Click Me!!!</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Does it work if you disable Shadow DOM? If not then it's probably connected to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#Clicking_and_focus

Comment: @Thomas Yes, it is. It was my ignorance to use activeElement to get clicked element. I found composedPath()[0] is suitable to get the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

I found the result to get the clicked element when shadowDom is enabled. Here is the solution:

```
  @Listen('click')
  onHadnleClickEvent(ev) {
    console.log('===== 31 =====', ev.composedPath()[0]// It will give you the clicked element
  }
```